# Search Xpath with its value in XML Documents and Get Document URI From Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

I have XML stored in MarkLogic as mentioned below

```
<testData>
  <datatypes>
    <datatypename>datatypename1</datatypename>
    <datatype>datatype1</datatype>
  </datatypes>
  <datavalue>
    <code>code1</code>
    <value>value1</value>
  </datavalue>
  <datavalue>
    <code>code2</code>
    <value>value2</value>
  </datavalue>
  <datavalue>
    <code>code3</code>
    <value>value3</value>
  </datavalue>
</testData>
```

and there is Possibility that Above values and document structure may Appear in another XML but with different URI.

So My Requirement is,  I need all the document URIs from the MarkLogic which contains `/testData/datatypes/datatypename` as exact xpath and its exact value as `datatypename1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward approach is to create a path range index on `/testData/datatypes/datatypename` and use a path range query:

```
cts:path-range-query("/testData/datatypes/datatypename", "=", "datatypename1")
```

An alternative is to use a values query within scoping element queries:

```
cts:element-query(xs:QName("testData"), 
  cts:element-query(xs:QName("datatypes"), 
    cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("datatypename"), "datatypename1")))
```

This approach is more susceptible to false positives. For small candidate result sets, such false positives can be mitigated by filtering.

For large candidate results sets, positional false positives (such as a document that has `testData/datatypes` and `datatypes/datatypename` but not `testData/datatypes/datatypename`) can be eliminated by indexing element positions. When punctuation is distinctive for the match, tokenization of the value will also produce false positives. In such cases, path range indexes are the correct solution for large candidate result sets.

Comment: IF you have the  ability to modify the XML format (schema), an alternative is to place datatypename (and possibly the entire document) in a different/unique namespace such that  '{namespace}datatypename' by itself is unique.  Then element value queries will be exact and even basic xpath is likely to be to be optimized (  e.g.     //ns:datatypename[. = "value"] )